# Match everything to the first unescaped (with \) character

Tags: regex

I have following input:

```
!foo\[bar[bB]uz\[xx/
```

I want to match everything from start to `[`, including escaped bracket `\[` and ommiting first characters if in `[!#\s]` group

Expected output:

```
foo\[bar
```

I've tried with:

```
(?![!#\s])[^/\s]+\[
```

But it returns:

```
foo\[bar[bB]uz\[
```

Comment: What language are you using? There may be more efficient syntax depending on the engine.

Comment: @zx81 BNF with regex (using https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit)

Comment: Is the whole Java regex syntax available with this plugin? In particular, can you use lookbehinds?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes, it is Java's regex.

Comment: Since it's a Java regex, the `\K` solutions won't work, but any of the lookbehind solutions on the page should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Java: Use Lookbehind**

```
(?<=!)(?:\\\[|[a-z])+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/5)

**Explanation**

- The lookbehind `(?<=!)` asserts that what precedes the current position is the character `!`
- The non-capture group `(?:\\\[|[a-z])` matches `\[` OR `|` a letter between `a` and `z`
- The `+` causes the group to be matched one or more times

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Answer (score 0):

- Add a `?` after `[^/\s]+` to catch the shortest group possible
- Add `\w+` to the end to catch the first group of alphanumeric characters after `\[`

Result :

```
(?![!#\s])[^\/\s]+?\[\w+
```

[**Try it**](http://regex101.com/r/nA9wB3/1)

Comment: \w isn't the expression for a word

Comment: `\w` is not, but `\w+` is... Same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`

Comment: that's not where i was going with this. Just clarifying that \w != word but alphanumeric CHARACTER. with everyone just asking questions on SO rather than learning regex themselves it's important to add that information

Comment: Ow, I see. I'll add this clarification in the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
!((?:[^[\\]*\\\[)*[^[]*)
```

#### [Online Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wM1cO3/4)

Comment: Just FYI - in this case first `^` is not acceptable

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern:

```
(?<=^[!#\s]{0,1000})(?:[^!#\s\\\[]|\\.)(?>[^\[\\]+|\\.)*(?=\[)
```

pattern details:

The begining is a lookbehind and means *preceded by zero or several forbidden characters at the start of the string*

`(?:[^!#\s\\\[]|\\.)` ensures that the first character is an allowed character or an escaped character.

`(?>[^\[\\]+|\\.)*` describes the content: *all that is not a `[` or a `\`, or an escaped character*. (note that this subpattern can be written like that too: `(?:[^\[\\]|\\.)*`)

`(?=\[)` checks that the next character is a literal opening square bracket. *(since all escaped characters are matched by the precedent group, you can be sure that this one is not escaped)*

**[link to fiddle](http://fiddle.re/3ytmp)** *(push the Java button)*

Answer (score 0):

Use a negated character class first the start (ie the match must *not* start with a special char), then a reluctant quantifier (which stops at the *first* hit), with a negative look behind to skip over escaped brackets:

```
[^!#\s].*?(?<!\\)\[
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/PTJtoRuHFG)